# automatic truncate author list in revtex4-1

Tags: bibliographies, revtex

I have a problem about using `revtex4-1`. This version does not automatically truncate long author lists anymore. So I followed the instruction I found here, I made an new `.bst` file through `makebst` and use `\bibliographystyle{mybstfile}`. But I got a strange  result as shown in the fig. below:

> all my ref. starting from [3], and I got something strange in [1] and
>   [2].

it looks like

> [1]
>
> [2],08..
>
> [3]normal ref. starting from here

I think, maybe revtex4-1 is written to show all the author list, so I found the older version `revtex4`, and use `\bibliographystyle{mybstfile}`, under this version and using my `bst` file, the ref. list is ok. However, I cannot use `superscriptaddress` in the `documentclass`, otherwise, I get the same crazy ref. list as before.

In other words, in order to have a normal ref. list, I am forced to use `groupedaddress` in the `documentclass` which will take a lot of space.

please, is there any one who can help me with this problem?

I am fine with both 4, or 4-1 version, as long as I can have a normal ref. list and `superscriptaddress` working properly in the same time...

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that you need to use a newer version of revtex4-1. With

```
Document Class: revtex4-1 2010/07/25/20:33:00 4.1r
```

there should not be a problem with using a `\bibliographystyle{...}` command, although there were problems with earlier releases.

Comment: I install revtex4-1 one year ago, and also re-install from https://authors.aps.org/revtex4/revtex4_faq.html last week. I think it must me the latest version, still, it just does not work....

Comment: Well, what is the version in the `\jobname.log` file?

Comment: I copy the beginning part of the log. file as following:     This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.11 (TeX Live 2010) (format=pdflatex 2010.7.21)  18 SEP 2012 15:46
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.                                            Is it what you are referring to?
 file:line:error style messages enabled.

Comment: No, I need the revtex version, which should look similar to how I wrote in my answer above.